# check for combinations in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two multiple choice questions with 9 possible choices, which makes up for 20 combinations of answers. Each combination is assigned a value. In excel,  I need to check answers for different combinations and tell me the value for that combination.

How is this possible? What formula do I need to use?

Example Q&A

[image: Questions and their answers]

Possible Answers

[image: Possible Answers]

Here's what I've tried it works but i need to make 20 such IF statements. Is there a better way?

```
=IF(B2 ="Squeaky clean",IF(C2="Just once","Normal"),IF(B2="A little tingly. Sometimes it stings",IF(C2="Just once","Sensitive")))
```

Comment: Do you want to do it in pure Excel or use VBA as well? What did you try so far?

Comment: Depending on the values, or how you want to do your check, you could use nested IF, a lookup table, CHOOSE.  Also there must be some relationship between the two questions or you would have 81 combinations instead of 20.  Knowing that relationship MIGHT help with the check of possible answers.

Comment: It all needs to be done on google sheets, I have tried doing it with if and or, but it got too complex too quickly. I don't know about lookup tables and choose sorry.

Comment: I have updated with an image of excel sheet you can see the relationships now.

Comment: So looking at your question 1 in column A, It reads from the screen shot as potentially 4 questions OR as 4 possible answer to Question 1.  Will B2, B3, B4 AND B5 all get a value?  If only one Value goes in column B, where does it go?  The same goes for Q2 in columns C and D.  How does column F work into this?  Another screen shot showing  a completed potential answer and your expected results (manual) might be helpful to clear some of this up.

Comment: After that i tried this IF statement 

=IF(((D2 ="Squeaky clean",IF(E2="Just once","Normal")),IF(D2="A little tingly. Sometimes it stings",IF(E2="Just once","Sensitive")),IF(D2="A little tight all over",IF(E2="Just once","Normal")),IF(D2="Tight across my forehead but otherwise it feels pretty good",IF(E2="Just once","Combination"))))


But it keeps giving me a parse error.

Comment: Just so you are aware, you have shifted your answers in your second image.  I also think I understand a lot better now.  And by the looks of your second screen shot you may have an answer table right there!

Comment: Yeah the previous screen didn't really explain it that well. Did you see the statement I'm using?  It might help you understand better what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so question 1 has 4 possible answers, Question 2 has 5 possible answer.  Each answer has a possible response which may or may not be unique.

I took the approach as treating each result to be unique.  There is nothing stopping you from repeating results though.

Build your self a table of Questions and Results.  Then where you want the results to appear, use the following formula and adjust the cell references to match your Q&A table.

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$21,SUMPRODUCT((A2=$D$2:$D$21)*(B2=$E$2:$E$21)*ROW($D$2:$D$21))-ROWS(1:1))
```

The sumproduct returns the row number where bother your Question 1 and Question 2 answers are found.

The -ROW(1:1) subtracts your header row count.  if you have two header rows about your Q&A Table you could use either -2 or -ROW(1:2).

Index looks through the results column of your Q&A table and returns the result corresponding to the row number from the sumproduct - headers rows

[image: Proof of Concept]

Now all if you follow the example and substitute you sentences for the letters, and put your results in columns F  you should have something that works for you.  Remember there is nothing stopping you from having the same result multiple times.  On a small data table this is not so bad.  IF you have the same result repeated multiple times on a large data table we could then look at a different approach.