# Create a truth table of results in an excel formula

Tags: excel, formula, truthtable

Based on two input conditions, I wish to be able to output 1 of 4 output values. For example when checking for matches between two tables I would like to be able to access a function like:

```
=TRUTHTABLE(condition1,condition2,true-true,true-false,false-true,false-false)
```

to do something like:

```
=TRUTHTABLE(MATCH(value,array1,0),MATCH(value,array2,0),"Good","Missing","Redundant","Good")
```

The two options I've come up with so far are:

```
=IF(condition1,IF(condition2,true-true,true-false),IF(condition2,false-true,false-false))
```

or:

```
=CHOOSE(1--condition1*2--condition2,false-false,false-true,true-false,true-true)
```

Option 1 is cumbersome to maintain due to the repetition of condition2, and option 2 is convoluted to understand for future maintainers. I'm currently tending toward option 2, but does anyone know any better option?

Comment: you are only dealing with 4 options so its relatively small to manage.  you could writ out the table in 4 rows and 3 columns,  Column A possibile results of condition1 match with possible results of condition 2 in column B.  Each pair/row forms a unique identifier.  Then you just look at your table for the row where condition 1 and condition 2 are true and return the result from column C in the matching row.

Comment: If I was using the formula just once or twice that could work, but I plan to have this repeated in every row of a column several hundred cells high.

Comment: [A potentially easier way to manage multiple if results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459915/check-for-combinations-in-excel/37463146#37463146) instead of going into a nest IF table.  As long as your four possible results remain the same, you should be able to copy the formula down beside your column of data.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go at that approach this afternoon.

Comment: The part of your question that reminded me of this was future maintainability.  Yes the formula is potentially crazy, but your table that you are going to check against is relatively easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for this, which I will keep in mind for future more complex occasions. For my current 2 x true/false the CHOOSE option seems best.

Answer (score 0):

With inputs of A1 and B1:

```
=LOWER(A1&"-"&B1)
```

A1 for example might contain:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(value,array1,0)))
```