# Excel 2007 Nested IF Formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, nested-if

I am trying to get a formula in which the results are all dates plus a certain number of days. I am getting an error while trying to add the days. This is the formula

=IF(R3=CECs!,"**10+CECs!F3**",IF(CECs!R3=CECs!B4,"30+CECs!F3",IF(CECs!R3=CECs!B5,"30+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B6,"30+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B7,"30+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B8,"30+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B9,"21+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B10,"AWAITING",IF(R3=CECs!B11,"10+CECs!F3",IF(R3=CECs!B12,"AWAITING",IF(R3=CECs!B13,"80+CECs!F3")))))))))))

If the cell has a value that is equal to a cell in another spreadsheet in the same workbook then it will add a certain number of days to a cell with a date. The bold section is where I am starting to get the error. Here I am trying to add 10 days to a date which is in the cell *CECs!F3*. 
Most of the other returns are a certain number of days added to a date value in a specific cell. 
So again the main problem is how do I add a number of days to a fixed date. 
I am using Excel 2007 btw.
If anyone can help me that would be great I've been trying to figure this out for a week now :(

Comment: Can you try removing the quotes?

Comment: Also, you need a cell reference at the first conditional. Maybe `IF(R3=CECs!A3...` or something like that.

Comment: information that is between "quotes" is taken as a string or text and not evaluated as a formula.

Comment: A good idea when you have a huge nested if statement like this is to take each if and place it in its own cell with the resulting conditions also placed in their own cells.  By breaking your ifs down like that you can determine which part of the if statement is not working.  When you get everything working, simply copy the formula from the dependent cells and paste them into the proceeding cells until everything is back in one formula.

Comment: what about this, can it work?=IF(Q3=Ack. Letter due 10 working days from stamped received date,B3+10,IF(Q3=Notification of decision due 30 working days from dispatch of ack. Letter,F3+30,IF(Q3=Notification of decision due30 working days from stamped received date of latest FI response,F3+30,IF(Q3=Notification of decision due in 30 working days,F3+30,IF(Q3=Notification of decision due in 30 working days,F3+30,IF(Q3=Notification of draft TOR due in 21 working days,F3+21,IF(Q3=Issue Final TOR within 10 days,F3+10,IF(Q3=Notification of decision due in 80 working days,F3+80)))))))))

Comment: where you have your sentences use quotes because they are strings/text. IF(Q3="sentence",B3+10,what to do if false).  The what to do if false can be another formula which could be your next if, or a string such as "OUT OF POSSIBILITIES" or "3rd IF FALSE VALUE".  If you do not supply a something to do, the IF statement will return FALSE by default if it has to go to the false option.

Comment: don't know what I did but it works now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

instead of a series of nested IF statement, you could make a table of responses.  Take a look at the [answer to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459915/check-for-combinations-in-excel/37463146#37463146).

If you build a table of conditions.  Each column being its own condition and the right most column being the results, you can see what conditions need to be met to get to certain results.  This can help you with building your logical check in IF statements or use other formulas like in the answer to that linked question that will return results for you.

You could also make a table of values and results and then use a lookup type function to get your results instead of of using nested IFs.  Ans example of this would be.

```
  A     |    B
Product | Result
Apples  |  1 a day to keep doctor away?
Beef    |  Where's the beef?
Car     |  Zoom Zoom!
Bear    |  Bear left, we go right!
```

so instead of saying something like:

```
IF(C1="Apples", "1 a day...",if(C1="Beef","Where's the..", etc
```

We can instead do a lookup

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$2:$B$5,2,0)
```

That would give the same results as a series of nested IF statements  There are also other ways of doing a lookup such as the LOOKUP formula and the INDEX and MATCH formulas working together.  Using the table method will just required you to store your options on another part of your worksheet out of the way or on a separate worksheet.

Tables tend to be easier to read and understand.  This is good when you or someone else has to deal with a worksheet a later date when the thought process on its development has been lost or forgotten.

In your case where you a looking at adding a certain number of days based on a text answer your table might look like:

```
   A    |   B 
C1 TEXT | DAYS TO
MATCH   | ADD To F2
----------------
  AAA   |   3
  BBB   |   7
  CCC   |  42

=F2+VLOOKUP(C1,A2:B4,2,0)
```